# Finding number of colors in an uploaded image (ignoring anti-aliasing/compression artifacts)?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

is there a way to find the number of colors in an uploaded image, ignoring the compression artifacts and anti-aliasing between colors?

I am creating a design tool that allows users to upload images, and I want it to return prices (which are based on colors in the image) in real-time without someone having to manually check each upload.

Only need 99% accuracy, fringe cases are okay.

Comment: Are you checking for spot colors?

Comment: Yes - looking for spot colors so we can price the file for printing

Comment: But I should clarify that we don't know if they'll be using high quality uploads or not.

Comment: In that, case, I think this is next to impossible. You'll have far too much artifacting and variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a tough time finding a pre-existing method for this. Spot colors such as Pantone Color matching System aren't color spaces, they are matching systems. As far as I know, there is no way to auto-detect PMS or other such matching systems.

**Edit based on comment below:**

Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagecolors.php

Comment: I don't need exact spot colors, if it were able to return hex values for the primary colors that would be fine.